# How to edit / remove tabs in search result page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, search-result

How can I edit or remove the tabs on top of the search result page?
I want to show the categories just above the results grid without inside of a tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You either have to find the page where those tabs are located and delete, or hide the tabs through css. To hide the tabs through css just use google inspect and get the class and just insert the code into your css.

```
.tabs-class{display:none !important;}
```